# Determine SVN node kind

Tags: svn, svnkit

I am using SVNkit api to download svn version history of a project and storing it in a database. I want to know if the changed path of a log entry is a file or a folder. SVNkit has SVNNodeKind class that can be used to find that. However it always returns "unknown" in my case. Somewhere I read that it might be because svn server might not be storing that information.

Also the changed paths do not contain trailing slashes for the directories. Is there any other way to find out if its a folder or a file.

Answer (score 2):

According to this [SVNkit example](http://wiki.svnkit.com/Printing_Out_A_Subversion_Repository_Tree) you can do this with the method of **SVNRepository** class:

```
abstract  SVNNodeKind checkPath(java.lang.String path, long revision) 
          Returns the kind of an item located at the specified path in a particular revision.
```

i.e. for the latest revision:

```
...
SVNNodeKind nodeKind = repository.checkPath( svnUrlToCheck ,  -1 );
if ( nodeKind == SVNNodeKind.NONE ) {
    System.err.println( "There is no entry at '" + url + "'." );
} else if ( nodeKind == SVNNodeKind.FILE ) {
    System.out.println( "Entry at '" + url + "' is file." );
} else if ( nodeKind == SVNNodeKind.DIR ) {
    System.out.println( "Entry at '" + url + "' is directory." );
} else if ( nodeKind == SVNNodeKind.UNKNOWN ) {
    System.out.println( "Entry at '" + url + "' is unknown!" );
}
```

The last **if** is for the case when SVN server doesn't support reporting node kind. It seems to be that it's supported always for **file:** protocol and for **svn:**, **svn+ssh:**, **http(s):** since version 1.6.0. but not always guaranteed.

Comment: Yes Since I have changed paths (SVNLogEntryPath) I used SVNLogEntryPath.getKind() which returns SVNNodeKind. However the value in SVNNodeKind is coming as "unknown".

Comment: Actually I tried again with SVNRepository.checkPath() and it does return the correct node kind.Thanks!

Comment: SVNLogEntryPath is the equivalent of the svn_log_changed_path2_t in the SVN C API ( http://subversion.apache.org/docs/api/1.7/structsvn__log__changed__path2__t.html )  This struct mentions that the node_kind might be unknown.  I'm forgetting what the conditions are for that, but I do recall that as @user1239080 mentioned you have to check the node kind separately in those cases.